# Derivation of Lighthill Equation

Tags: waves, conservation-laws, acoustics, navier-stokes

I'm trying to understand the meaning of Lighthill equation. Based on my text book (sound and source of sound, Dowling and Williams 1983), it is derived from combining mass conservation and momentum conservation equations.
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\rho v_i \right) = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\rho v_i)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(p_{ij}+\rho v_iv_j) = 0$$
where $p_{ij}=p'\delta_{ij}-\tau_{ij}$, $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta function. $\tau_{ij}$ is the viscous stress. If we subtract $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ for the first equation and $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ for the second equation, we can obtain
$$\frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial^2 \rho'}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(\rho v_iv_j+p_{ij})$$
and then subtract from both sides,
$$ c^2 \nabla^2\rho'=c^2\frac{\partial\rho'\delta_{ij}}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$$
Then we can get Lighthill eaution
$$\frac{\partial^2 \rho'}{\partial t^2}-c^2\nabla^2\rho' = \frac{\partial^2 T_{ij}}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$$
$$ T_{ij}=\rho v_i v_j +p_{ij}-c^2 \rho' \delta_{ij}$$

- Now I'm confusing which terms are total, mean and fluctuation. If my understanding is correct variables that have ' are fluctuations and others are total of time average and fluctuation. Is this correct?
  If this is correct, why $p_{ij}$ is not defined as $p_{ij} = (p_0+p')\delta_{ij}-\tau_{ij}$?
- Is the momentum equation is Reynolds form? What does $\rho v_i v_j$ indicate?